# I have a problem: type '() => Null' is not a subtype of type '(int) => void' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I started studying mobile development and had a lot of questions and problems. I have classes. I'm passing a field value "score" and getting an error. Help me to understand. Thank you.
My error: type '() => Null' is not a subtype of type '(int) => void' in type cast

this's main

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const _questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Red', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Blue', 'score': 7},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Yellow', 'score': 2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What do you do?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Eat', 'score': 9},
        {'text': 'Sleep', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Drink water', 'score': 4},
        {'text': 'Run', 'score': 3},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Do you have chairs?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Yes', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'No', 'score': 1},
        {'text': 'A lot', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'I don\'t know', 'score': 7},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'Would you like some red wine?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Yes', 'score': 1},
        {'text': 'No', 'score': 9},
        {'text': 'I don\'t drink alcohol', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'No, I would like soda', 'score': 7},
      ],
    },
  ];

  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var _totalScore = 0;

  void _answerQuiz(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'QuiZ',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Quiz'),
        ),
        body: _questionIndex < _questions.length
            ? Quiz(
                questions: _questions,
                questionIndex: _questionIndex,
                answerQuestion: _answerQuiz,
              )
            : Result(_totalScore),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this's class Quiz

```
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final void Function(int) answerQuestion;
  // final VoidCallback answerQuestion;

  const Quiz({
    required this.questions,
    required this.questionIndex,
    required this.answerQuestion,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Question(questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String),
          ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
              .map((answer) {
            return Answer(
              answer['text'] as String,
                () {
                  answerQuestion(answer['score'] as int);
                } as void Function(int p1),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this's class Answer

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String answerText;
  final void Function(int) selectHandler;
  // final VoidCallback selectHandler;

  const Answer(this.answerText, this.selectHandler, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: const ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.cyan),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.blueAccent),
      ),
      onPressed: () => selectHandler,
      child: Text(answerText),
    );
  }
}
```

and this class Result

```
class Result extends StatelessWidget {
  final int resultScore;
  const Result(this.resultScore, {super.key});

  String get resultPhrase {
    var resultText = 'You did it';
    if (resultScore <= 8) {
      resultText = 'You are awesome and innocent';
    } else if (resultScore <= 12) {
      resultText = 'Pretty likeable';
    } else if (resultScore <= 16) {
      resultText = 'You are ... strange?!';
    } else {
      resultText = 'You are so bad!!!';
    }

    return resultText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(resultPhrase),
    );
  }
}
```

I expected to get the value "score"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is ony Answer class

the `onpressed` parameter of ElevatedButton dont receive the type of fuction you want to pass.

fix it by doing this:
Corrected the **onPressed** line to **onPressed: selectHandler**.

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String answerText;
  final void Function() selectHandler;
  // final VoidCallback selectHandler;

  const Answer(this.answerText, this.selectHandler, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: const ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.cyan),
        foregroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.blueAccent),
      ),
      onPressed: selectHandler, //call the function properly
      child: Text(answerText),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What would you recommend for me to read? I will be grateful to you for your answer and advice)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the purpose of `selectHandler` in `Answer` is to pass the pressed event to the `Quiz` widget, so you don't need to make the function type `void Function(int)` (and you're not providing any `int` value from `Answer` anyway. Instead, you can make it a `VoidCallback` and change the way it's being passed to the `onPressed` parameter:

```dart
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  // ...
  final VoidCallback selectHandler; // (1) change the type

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      // ...
      onPressed: selectHandler, // (2) pass it as a tear-off
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

In `Quiz`, there's no need to cast the function type:

```dart
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Question(questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String),
          ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
              .map((answer) {
            return Answer(
              answer['text'] as String,
                () {
                  answerQuestion(answer['score'] as int);
                }, // (1) remove the type cast
            );
          }).toList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What would you recommend for me to read? I will be grateful to you for your answer and advice

Comment: This should give you a good grasp of various functions in Dart: [Functions](https://dart.dev/language/functions), and this one has a good explanation of substituting types in Dart: [Substituting types](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#substituting-types)

Comment: excelent, @DhafinRayhan
when using a fltuter widget,take a look into documentation about the widget   , https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets